# How to fix a "positional argument" error when trying to implement a row

Tags: flutter, dart

I am pretty new to dart programming, coming from a more basic language and got this error when trying to implement a row. "Error: Place positional arguments before named arguments. Try moving the positional argument before the named arguments, or add a name to the argument". Any help would be appreciated and the code is included below.

```
Row( 
    children: [

     TextButton(
       onPressed: tempoRandomise,
       child: Icon(Icons.add),
     ),
    TextButton(
       onPressed: keyRandomise,
       child: Icon(Icons.add),
     ),
     TextButton(
       onPressed: styleRandomise,
       child: Icon(Icons.add),
     ),
   ],
  )
```

Comment: are you sure about the error being in these lines?

Comment: thats where terminal says it is

Comment: provide a bigger code sample, maybe you haven't written `child:` befor Row

Comment: terminal shows on which line of which file, and post that code

Answer (score 0):

Based on what you sent, it could be from the `onPressed`. It seems that you are passing some parameters to for example, `styleRandomise`. Try to use the code below:

```
TextButton(
    child: Icon(Icons.add),
    onPressed: ( ) {
          print('Pressed');
     }
)
```

Or you may declare your `styleRandomise` function like below and use your existing code:

```
void styleRandomise ( ) {
    print('Do something here...');
}
```

Don't forget to check other functions you stated in front of `onPressed`. They all must have no parameter and void.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Ive defined all of the functions in previous lines, so I'm not sure why it would do that. Ill give it a try tho, thanks